# Could not build wheels for matplotlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pip

In my Python project, executing python install -r requirements.txt results in the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtZbQ.png)

```
 Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/50/e2/8e10e465ee3987bb7c9ab69efb91d867d93959095f4807db102d07995d94/more_itertools-10.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: matplotlib
  Building wheel for matplotlib (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [593 lines of output]

      Edit setup.cfg to change the build options; suppress output with --quiet.

      BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
        matplotlib: yes [3.3.2]
            python: yes [3.10.13 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Sep 11 2023,
                        13:24:38) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]]
          platform: yes [win32]
       sample_data: yes [installing]
             tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
            macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
.....
on-310\matplotlib\_version.py
      set build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\matplotlib\_version.py to '3.3.2'
      running build_ext
      Extracting freetype-2.6.1.tar.gz
      Building freetype in build\freetype-2.6.1
      msbuild build\freetype-2.6.1\builds\windows\vc2010\freetype.sln /t:Clean;Build /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64
      error: command 'msbuild' failed: None
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for matplotlib
  Running setup.py clean for matplotlib
Failed to build matplotlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for matplotlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've looked at a lot of solutions online and they haven't worked out